# How I can iterate a nested object to acces to their values in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, nested

I've searched a lot for this and I don't get a suitable answer to solve this. I have an object that I've made from a fetched data and the structure is like this:

```
{
      id: string,
      title: string,
      price: {
        currency: string,
        amount: number,
      },
      picture: string,
      condition: string,
      free_shipping: string,
      sold_quantity: string,
    };
```

When I try to iterate through the nested object (second level)

```
price: {
        currency: string,
        amount: number,
      },
```

console **throws an error** to *undefined*. I've tried: **Object.keys()** method or transform the object into an array without success.

Does anyone know how I can iterate through this object **and obtain the values of each property**: *currency, amount*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do?  We can't help fix code if we can't see what it's doing. If you are trying to iterate an object though I imagine it'll look something like `Object.entries(data.price)` to get an array of key-value pairs of the nested property, or `Object.values(data.price)` for just the values.

Comment: You want to *iterate* but there's no array here, just access the `price` property with `yourData.price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly understand the issue, we do need to see exactly how you are trying to iterate your object. The short answer in how to do this, as mentioned by other users is

```js
Object.keys(obj).map((key) => { 
    const value = obj[key]
    // Do stuff with value (?)
    return value
})
```

Of course, for the example above, we will not properly access the keys of your nested object (`price`), for that to happen you'd have to do an `Object.keys(obj).map(()=>{})` within the one you already have. So something like this:

```js
Object.keys(obj).map((key) => { 
    const value = obj[key]
    // Do stuff with value (?)
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        const nestedObjectKeys = Object.keys(value).map((nestedKey) => {
            // Do stuff
        })
    }
    return value
})
})
```

This is where we do need more details about your question, if you know that that is what you want to access and iterate through, just use the same thing, but directly on the `price` object. Should look like this:

```js
Object.keys(obj.price).map((key) => { 
    const priceValue = obj.price[key]
    // Do stuff with priceValue (?)
    return priceValue
 })
```

Here is a simple demo with both cases:

```js
const App = () => {

const obj = {
    id: 'my_id',
    title: 'my_title',
    price: {
        currency: 'USD',
        amount: 100,
    },
    picture: 'my_picture',
    condition: 'my_conditon',
    free_shipping: 'free_shipping',
    sold_quantity: 'sold_quantity',
};


  return (
  <div>
    <h3>Example 1: Iterating through the whole object</h3>
    {Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      const value = obj[key]
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          {typeof value === 'object'
            ? (
              <div>
                <hr/>
                <h4>Found a nested object! Lets now do another Object.keys().map!</h4>
                {Object.keys(value).map((nestedKey) => (
                  <div key={nestedKey}>{nestedKey}: {value[nestedKey]}</div>
                ))}
                <hr/>
              </div>
            )
            : <span>{key}: {value}</span>
           }
        </div>
      )
    })}
    
    <h3>Example 2: Simply iterating only through the nested object</h3>
    {Object.keys(obj.price).map((key) => (
      <div key={key}>
        {key}: {obj.price[key]}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Edit: as Drew Reese pointed out, in this case there is actually no reason to iterate through the keys instead of the values (Object.keys(obj) vs Object.values(obj)). Unless you for some reason need access to the keys. everything described above could be done in a more cleaner fashion with `Object.values(obj)`. So the examples may then become:

```js
Object.values(obj).map((value) => {
   // Do stuff with value (?)
   return value
})
```

and

```js
Object.values(obj.price).map((value) => {
   // Do stuff with value (?)
   return value
})
```

Comment: Why would you iterate the keys just to get the values when you can just iterate the values instead?

Comment: Idk. I forget Object.values() is a thing (not a very good excuse, I know XD). Will update it with that note.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm really appreciate the answers to my question. It was really helpful!

In fact, my mistake was from the state that I've defined inside my code. I'll try to explain it in the next lines.

This object structure (below) was made for me to receive the data from an API:

```
{
  id: string,
  title: string,
  price: {
    currency: string,
    amount: number,
  },
  picture: string,
  condition: string,
  free_shipping: string,
  sold_quantity: string,
};
```

The API doesn't maintain the same structure that I show you below, so I have to resample in the promise on the fetch. But when I made the resample, I didn't insert the price `object`.

So, when I try to use `Obj.map`. React explodes and said to me that it cannot iterate on an `undefined`.

That was really a headache because I was trying to understand why I cannot iterate over a nested object. But, in the end, that was not the base issue.

And finally, the way to integrate the data fetched from the API and later transformed to my desire structure was more simple than I thought.

Just with the dot notation, I could access the specific item that I've need from the object and object nested. for example:

```
item.price.amount // Returns 1990
item.price.currency // Returns USD
```

Hope this answer could help you. But this issue makes me understand fully deep how to iterate objects through `Objects.keys(obj).map(key =>(//code))`

Especial thanks to @theJuls for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this method?

```js
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
  
});
```